# exclude file in Git Template directory does not work

Tags: git, configuration, gitignore

I am trying to exclude all text documents in my dummy repo as what my textbook suggested. Using my desktop's GUI (and not the terminal), I copied and pasted the exclude file from the git-core `git-core/templates/info` into my own template file.

I then did `echo "*.txt"  > exclude`

After that, I then ran this command `git config --global init.templatedir C:/Users/youse/Documents/"Web Development" /learning_git/.git_template`

As you can see, I made sure the path was absolute.

I then did `git init` and made a txt file in the repo, yet it still allows me to do `git add`. What did I do wrong here? There was a stackoverflow inquiry regarding this, and it talked about .gitignore. Forgive me, but I don't see a `.gitignore`

If anyone has an explanation, I would be very grateful.

```bash
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        txt2.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Can you check if your edited `exclude` is in `.git/info/`? Works for me. I created a bare repo as a template, edited `echo "*.txt" > info/exclude`, initialized a new repo with this template: `git init --template=template.git` — the file `info/exclude` was copied. I created a file `echo test > test.txt` and the new file was ignored. No problem.

Comment: @phd sorry for the late reply as I was traveling, anyways, I ran .git/info/exclude file and it gave me "*.txt".

Comment: @phd so it seems that I did reassign the default template folder; however, ,maybe there is something wrong with the exclude configuration? as in I wrote "*.txt" and it copies it to all git repos but it still does add text files. Keep in mind, I know nothing about exclude :).

Comment: Can we see the output of `git status` that shows some of these `.txt` files? Please [edit] and copy/paste text output.

Comment: @phd done, anything else?

Comment: Oops, very strange. Should be ignored but it's not. Then the problem is in `.git/info/exclude`. Can you open it (in this repository, not in template) in an editor that could show file encoding — is the file ASCII? No extra characters (like BOM) at the beginning? Just one line `*.txt` and nothing else? In Git-bash: `cat -Et .git/info/exclude` to see special characters including line ends as `$`

Comment: @phd There seems to be an extra character! My output is: "*.txt" ^M$

Comment: That's normal, I think. `^M` is a CR (carriage return, `\r`) character before a new line (`\n`). This is DOS/Windows line ending; they use 2-characters EOL CR+LF; Unixen use just LF, MacOS uses just CR. Well, I'm out of ideas to check, sorry. Everything look good, just don't work.

Comment: I'm started to smell things. Are the double quotes really in the file? You wrote `"*.txt" ^M$` — are these `"` there? They shouldn't be. The file `.git/info/exclude` must contain just `*.txt` (`*.txt^M$` in `cat -Et` output) — no quotes, no spaces.

Comment: @phd how do I remove them?

Comment: Interesting… I wonder how comes that `echo "*.txt"  > exclude` preserved quotes? Was it Powershell?

Comment: @phd no actually, I was using bash :)

Comment: I'm absolutely and completely puzzled! :-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `.git/info/exclude` must contain just `*.txt` (`*.txt^M$` in `cat -Et` output) — no quotes, no spaces.

Now you need to fix your template repository and all repositories already created from the template. Manually, alas!

Answer (score 0):

When initialing your git repository you should have done it using:

git init --template= ..\template-location

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Then you would have created it using the template you created earlier.

In addition,
You can also create .gitignore file and add any file extension you want, the exact same way like you did which will be used specifically for your repository.
Push to the repository to share with all contributors.
Note that .gitignore will need to be created manually for every new repo.

Comment: **1**. What is wrong with [`git config --global 
init.templateDir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-inittemplateDir)? That the how the OP uses template repo. **2**, `.gitignore` cannot be copied from [template directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory) because the name starts with a dot; so it must be created manually in every repo while the OP wants this to be automatic in all new repos.

Comment: 1. As mentioned above, you need to initialize the repository using your template. After you configure the template, initialize a repo using it.
2. .gitignore is another option to ignore file extensions, but indeed you'll need to create one manually for every repository you create.

Comment: 1. The OP did exactly that using configured template repo, why `.git/info/exclude` was not copied?